# NHibernate lazy bidirectional map for hierarchy

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following domain model structure:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    public virtual B1 B1 { get; set;}
    public virtual B2 B2 { get; set;}
}

class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    public virtual string Discriminator { get; set;}
    public virtual A A { get; set;}
}

class B1 : B
{
}

class B2 : B
{
}
```

Database table structure:

```
A_table (Id)
B_table (Id, Discriminator, AId);
```

where column AId is  **nullable** foreign key.

So how do I create the bidirectional map in `NHibernate` (mapping by code), with lazy B1, B2 links?

**UPD1:**
If I set `property-ref` in mapping config, bidirectional map works fine, but links is not lazy:

```
<one-to-one name="B1" cascade="all" property-ref="A" />
<one-to-one name="B2" cascade="all" property-ref="A" />
```

Have any ideas how setup lazy in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't!!!

Here why:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    // As you don't have a B1Id column, this is a OneToMany relation (a List, Set, etc)
    public virtual B1 B1 { get; set; }

    // As you don't have a B2Id column, this is a OneToMany relation (a List, Set, etc)
    public virtual B2 B2 { get; set; }
}
```

What you are trying to do is a *OneToOne* mapping and for this, both **A** and **B** tables must have the same *Id* (this is a *OneToOne*).

For two entities to reference each other without a *OneToOne* relation you actually have a list. As your model shows it:

```
A_table (Id)
B_table (Id, Discriminator, AId);
```

The *A* table has an 0..n relation with *B*.

Please note the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO A_table (Id) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO B_table (Id, Discriminator, AId) VALUES (1, 'B1', 1)
INSERT INTO B_table (Id, Discriminator, AId) VALUES (2, 'B1', 1)
INSERT INTO B_table (Id, Discriminator, AId) VALUES (3, 'B2', 1)
INSERT INTO B_table (Id, Discriminator, AId) VALUES (4, 'B2', 1)
```

As you see, both *A.B1* and *A.B2* will have two values each.